# How i remove geometric forms same color to text from captcha?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to remove a thresh lines and forms from a specific captcha.

I removed a lot, but I have some problem now... In this captcha, I have specific geometric forms same color as text, like an example above.

[image]

I've made a code who remove a lot of this thrash captcha, like this.

[image]

But now i have this same pattern in all of captchas, this circle null tesseract, is there any way to get it out?

Comment: could you please share the code you have used uptil now. It will then be easier to provide suggestions on what more can be done.

Comment: my code is very simple, I just remove all the colors that are different from the text itself, all the texts have the same color